# Dynamic data in Cross Tab of Birt Tool

Tags: birt

how to hide cross tab columns runtimely based on user selection in birt Tool

Comment: Probably need to add some javascript to do it

Answer (score 0):

See the attached image...[image]

Comment: OP is asking about crosstabs, not tables.

Answer (score 0):

Rows and columns can be removed from visibility in BIRT cross tabs by filtering the cross tab.

To do this:

- Select the crosstab object in the Layout window.
- In the Property Editor for the cross tab, select the Filters tab.
- Click the `Add...` button to the right of the `Filter by:` list.

  - In the New Filter Condition dialog, select the desired column from the `Target:` section and the relevant conditions in the `Filter Condition:` section. Remember that filter conditions are conditions for showing the data, not hiding it, so your condition will need to be the converse of a condition for hiding it (such as would be used in a table column visibility condition).

Comment: hi mark   its good, but my Quesition is based on user input like report parameters ,i want to hide rows or columns of cross tab

Comment: @venkatch: Yes, to include groups that match the entered parameter, specify the `Filter Condition:` match condition as `Equal to` (or `In`, for multi-valued parameters) and the `Filter Condition:` Value as the parameter using the `fx` button, in the New Filter Condition dialog.

Comment: HI mark i have multiple Rows and I dont have specific names to that rows, how can i hide that rows based user inputs

Comment: Expand your question to include the data structure of your dataset, the structure of your cubes and which rows/columns you want the users to be able to include/exclude.

Comment: hi  mark, my cross tab contains (year,state,model) rows,  for example i am displaing data like year wise states,state wise models , model wise cost and state wise sub totals

Answer (score 0):

Use cross-tab to tabulate dynamic columned data. Follow [this tutorial](https://birttutorial.blogspot.com/2017/05/birt-cross-tab-for-dynamic-columned.html) to create dynamic columned cross-tab report