# Expand and collapse (drilling) in cross tab BIRT

Tags: eclipse, birt, crosstab, data-cube

I have implemented a data cube that shows the population in each year(rows). The top grouping is on the continent and the next level of grouping is continents. I would like to place a + symbol against each continent, when clicked breaks the population on country wise, then then another level of grouping at the state level and  so on. Is it possible to implement this is BIRT.

[Dynamic data in Cross Tab of Birt Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936650/dynamic-data-in-cross-tab-of-birt-tool) is not accepted yet, apologize if my question is duplicated.

Regards,

Nandish

Comment: "The top grouping is on the continent and the next level of grouping is continents" - should that be "The top grouping is on the continent and the next level of grouping is **countries**"?

Comment: @Nandish have you find the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this Eclipse Forum post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/81843/254153/0721fcbf90e6161c6e591e524db0f57b/#msg_254153), drilldown/drillup functionality in crosstabs should have been added to BIRT 2.3.1 - however, I have not seen it in more recent versions of BIRT. It is available in the [BIRT Data Analyzer](http://www.birt-exchange.com/be/products/birt-user-experience/analytics/features/birt-data-analyzer/), although this is not a part of the BIRT Community edition.

Comment: Hi Mark your link of "BIRT Data Analyzer" is not working. Could you provide it's another solution please?